# Advanced “skip page” logic in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to skip from one page and have the user go to another? Example: Page 1 has yes/no field, if yes goto page 2 and if no goto page 3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely!  When you add [Page Breaks](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/multi-page-forms) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can select `Show Next Page - When` to specify whether the page following a page break should be available.  This will allow you to enter conditional logic such that when the answer to the question on Page 1 is Yes, then Page 2 is shown when the user clicks Next. This also affects the pages that appear in the progress bar and what pages are included in printed documents.

[image]